# Webix: how to dynamically load components from external js file into a layout?

Tags: webix

I would like to know how to update a row/col and or layout from an external js file on webix. Let's say I have a menu at the left of the screen (col[]) and want to update the right column based on a menu selection. If the menu is composed by

1. Customers
2. Orders
3. Products

And want to update the right column based on the selection calling customers.js, orders.js and products.js

Just like http://webix.com/demos/admin-app/#!/app/orders

That example is very advanced for me, I would like to learn some basic method.
Thanks
Oscar P

Answer (score 0):

You can use webix.ui command or addView API to add a new UI to some specific place on the page.

```
webix.ajax("config.json", function(text){
    $$("layout").addView( JSON.parse(text) );
})
```

or

```
webix.ajax("config.json", function(text){
    webix.ui( JSON.parse(text), $$("cell_to_replace"));
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aquatic, I haven't try yet your suggestion but what happen with the logic if I get a .json file related with the menu option I need to call? as far as I know we can only add functions and logic in a .js file, am I right? if so, can I call .js with an webix.ajax()?

Comment: Hi, I already made a sample with webix.ui and works but just once: let's say I have a menu with "Customers" and "Employees", works at the first time and changes ok from "Customers" to "Employees" but doesn't work when I want to open "Customers" back.

Answer (score 0):

Aquatic,

I also found out an example with .showBatch() API but the console shows "Uncaught TypeError: $$(...).addView is not a function" on both functions, are those part of PRO version? what is wrong?
My code is:

$$("workArea").addView("clientes"); 
or
$$("workArea").showBatch("batClientes");

```
on:{
    onMenuItemClick:function(id) {
      $$("workArea").addView(id);
    }
  }
```